# Bracket problem

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document
\begin{align*}
    & \frac{1}{2} (1-\varepsilon^2)\left(\partial_\tau \phi\right)^2\\
    & = \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\epsilon ^2\right)\left(
      -\frac{S \epsilon \sin\tau }{\sqrt{\lambda }}
      -\frac{g_2 S^2 \epsilon ^2\sin2\tau }{3 \lambda }\right.\\
    & \quad\left. +\epsilon ^3 \left(-\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{54} g_2^2 S
      \left(32+19 S^2\right) \lambda +Z \left(
      \frac{35 g_2^4}{27}
      -\frac{7 g_2 g_4}{4}+\frac{5 g_5}{8}
      -\frac{g_2^2 \lambda }{6}
      +\frac{\lambda ^2}{24}\right)\right) \sin\tau}
      {\lambda ^{5/2}}\right.\right.\\
    & \quad\left.\left.-\frac{S^3 \left(4 g_2^2-3 \lambda \right) \sin3\tau }
      {24 \lambda ^{3/2}}\right)\right)^2 \\
    & = \frac{S^2 \epsilon ^2 \sin^2\tau }{2 \lambda }+\frac{2 g_2S^3 \epsilon ^3 \cos\tau \sin^2\tau  }{3 \lambda ^{3/2}}  \\
    & \quad +\frac{1}{216 \lambda ^3}S \epsilon ^4 \Bigl( 280 g_2^4 Z-378 g_2 g_4 Z+135 g_5 Z-128 g_2^2 S \lambda  -16 g_2^2 S^3 \lambda \\
    & \quad -36 \text{g2}^2 Z \lambda  -108 S \lambda ^2-27 S^3 \lambda ^2+9 Z \lambda ^2+6 S^3 \left(16 g_2^2-9 \lambda \right) \lambda  \cos2 \tau \Bigr) \sin\tau.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In the above code I found an inconsistency with the brackets. I marked it in the following picture:

[image].

I tried to remove this, but when I did so, I got an error. Can you check this please?

Comment: You cannot use `\left.` and `\right.` in this situation. They measure the contents and they do not have equal size. Manually scale instead using, say. `\bigg` or `\Bigg`.

Comment: Can you also show *your* attempt to solve the issue?

Comment: as @daleif said or you could get rid of the fraction and multiply by `\lambda^{-5/2}` instead, then you wouldn't need big brackets

Comment: Use a `\right.` in the line with the large parenthesis. Use a `\left.` in the line with the wrong parenthesis but put in a '\vphantom{stuff}`, where `stuff` is the fraction in the previous line. This should scale the parenthesis to the proper size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My rewrite. I've removed quite a lot of unnecessary `\left...\right` pairs. Plus I mixed the brackets. `((((` is no the easiest to keep track of for the reader.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \MoveEqLeft[3] 
  \tfrac{1}{2} (1-\varepsilon^2)\left(\partial_\tau \phi\right)^2
  \\
  ={} & \frac{1}{2} 
  (1-\epsilon ^2)
  \Biggl[ -\frac{S\epsilon \sin\tau }{\sqrt{\lambda } } 
  -\frac{g_2 S^2 \epsilon^2\sin2\tau }{3 \lambda }
  \\
  &  +\epsilon ^3 
  \Biggl(-\frac{
    \left\{
      -\frac{1}{54}
      g_2^2 S (32+19 S^2) \lambda 
      +Z \left(
        \frac{35 g_2^4}{27} -\frac{7 g_2 g_4}{4}
        +\frac{5g_5}{8} 
        -\frac{g_2^2 \lambda }{6} 
        +\frac{\lambda^2}{24}
      \right)
    \right\}
    \sin\tau} 
  {\lambda ^{5/2}}
  \\
  & -\frac{S^3 (4 g_2^2-3 \lambda)
    \sin3\tau } {24 \lambda ^{3/2}}\Biggr)
  \Biggr]^2
  \\
  ={} & \frac{S^2 \epsilon ^2 \sin^2\tau }{2 \lambda }+\frac{2
    g_2S^3 \epsilon ^3 \cos\tau \sin^2\tau }{3 \lambda ^{3/2}}
  \\
  & +\frac{1}{216 \lambda ^3}S \epsilon ^4 \Bigl( 280 g_2^4
  Z-378 g_2 g_4 Z+135 g_5 Z-128 g_2^2 S \lambda -16 g_2^2 S^3
  \lambda
  \\
  & -36 \text{g2}^2 Z \lambda -108 S \lambda ^2-27 S^3
  \lambda ^2+9 Z \lambda ^2+6 S^3 (16 g_2^2-9 \lambda)
  \lambda \cos2 \tau \Bigr) \sin\tau.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check your code once more please, cause it is not showing output

Comment: @ComplexGuy the code compiles just fine. Exactly which error do you get?

Comment: If you replace `\Bigg[` and `\Bigg(` with `\Biggl[` and `\Biggl(`, the subsequent `-` (minus) symbols will be treated as *unary* rather than as *binary* operators. :-)

Comment: @Mico, of course, code updated, though I'm leaving the image